# Using MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit terminal on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, msys2

There's a lot of tutorials about how to using MSYS2 terminal on VSCode. But we know there are 3 shells:

- MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit
- MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit
- MSYS2 MSYS

But if I set `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` to `"C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe"`, I can only use MSYS2 MSYS. I want to use MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit because I don't want my programs required `msys-2.0.dll`

Can somebody teach me how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried use mingw32.exe or mingw64.exe directly?

Answer (score 5):

This work for me:

```
{
     "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe", 
     "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login", "-i"],
     "terminal.integrated.env.windows": { 
          "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64", 
          "CHERE_INVOKING":"1" } 
}
```

Pls. refer to: [How do I integrate MSYS2 shell into Visual studio code on Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836650/how-do-i-integrate-msys2-shell-into-visual-studio-code-on-window)

Comment: For other readers, the meat of the answer is the "MSYSTEM" environment variable, which tells MSYS2 which environment to use (MSYS2, MINGW32/64, CLANG32/64)

Comment: Also, one should now use terminal profiles rather than hard-coding the shell. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68253833) in the question mention above.