# MSys2 bash in VS Code starts separate window

Tags: msys2

I am able to set up in Workspace Settings for VS Code that my internal terminal should be a MSys2 bash shell. However the shell is started as an external shell, not internal. This does not happen for ex with git shell or ubuntu sub system shell

I have tried different settings found here:
[How do I integrate MSYS2 shell into Visual studio code on Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836650/how-do-i-integrate-msys2-shell-into-visual-studio-code-on-window)

No code to show, look at examples provided in the link to the other stackoverflow post.

I would expect the shell to be started as an internal shell to VS code

Answer (score 0):

Append the user settings with the following JSON code:

```
// MSYS2
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login", "-i"],
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "CHERE_INVOKING": "1"
},
```