# How to use msys2 command "gcc, make" in integrated VSCode terminal

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, makefile, msys2

I've done things in this question [How do I integrate MSYS2 shell into Visual studio code on Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836650/how-do-i-integrate-msys2-shell-into-visual-studio-code-on-window)
However, I cannot run make or gcc like the msys2.exe
So how to use the exact terminal like msys2.exe do in the integrated vscode terminal
Thank you!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the [difference betweem MSYSTEMs](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/)? You should be comparing VSC shell not to a `MSYS` one, but to a `MINGW64` one (start it using `mingw64.exe`).

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` print (a) in VSC, (b) in the MSYS shell (the second one on the screenshot), and (c) in MINGW64 shell (the one that you can start with `mingw64.exe`)?