# Lauching MSYS2 32-bit console from visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, mingw-w64, msys2, mingw32

I want to integrate the 32-bit-mingw-MSYS2 console in Visual Studio Code.
I have tried to understand that:
[How do I integrate MSYS2 shell into Visual studio code on Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836650/how-do-i-integrate-msys2-shell-into-visual-studio-code-on-window)

My settings.json file looks like:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "MSYS MinGW x32": {
            "path": "D:\\Software\\MSYS2\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "env": {
                "MSYSTEM": "MINGW32",
              },
            "args": []
        },
```

However, when I open the console, it seems that not the 32-bit-shell but the 64-bit one is launched.

To launch the 32-bit-one from the normal windows terminal, I have to say:

```
D:\Software\MSYS2\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32
```

If I change above settings.json file to

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "MSYS MinGW x32": {
                "path": "D:\Software\MSYS2\msys2_shell.cmd",
                "args": ["-mingw32"]
            },
```

the correct shell is launched but in a new window (not integrated in Visual Studio Code). Also this new shell is not launched in the directory I am currently working in Visual Studio Code, which would be my wish.
The msys2_shell.cmd can take a command line option

```
-where Directory
```

but what would you need to tell the settings.json file, so that this shell is always launched in the current directory of Visual Studio Code (which I see in the file explorer)

Any help appreciated!